# Loss decreasing after each step in an epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

As per my understanding the loss would decrease after an epoch, but why while training a model the loss value is decreasing after each step in an epoch? Backpropagation happens only once in an epoch or does it happen at each step in an epoch?

This is probably a silly question, but I couldn't find answer anywhere. If there is already a question regarding this, please post the link.

Comment: Gradient descent happens at each step in an epoch, backpropagation is just a way to compute the gradient. Gradient descent is the actual thing that  updates the weights.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I thought that the weights would be updated once in an epoch. If the weights are updated after each step (by gradient descent), then what exactly is an epoch?

Comment: An epoch is just a pass over the whole dataset, where gradients and computed and weights updated on each minibatch.